# Android playstatechanged

Tags: android, intentfilter

So im trying to figure out when user pauses a song in spotify/android native player. I have

```
        iF.addAction("com.spotify.music.playstatechanged");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
```

in my intent filter and im trying to save boolean value of playing inside broadcast receiver like this

```
        isPlaying = intent.getBooleanExtra("playing", true);
```

Problem here is that pausing a song does absolutely nothing to the variable isPlaying. Does playstatechanged not broadcast or what seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/android-media-notifications/) tutorial taken from **Spotify**'s dev portal, the action of the intent is **com.spotify.music.playbackstatechanged**.

Comment: I knew its was something stupidly simple like that, thanks :)